# How to protect app to be opened from other app which has same scheme and host?

Tags: javascript, android, android-launcher

I have SplashActivity in that I am using 2 Intent-Filter one is the default (Launcher) and other one scheme and host for the app to open by the website from the browser. I don't have enough knowledge. My question is if any other app having different package id but same scheme and same host, can that app to be opened by website(mobile browser)?.Please help me with this.

**Code:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="com.******.***" android:host="www.******.com"  />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple app with same host name and scheme, system will show action chooser with list of apps and you need to choose app to be open.

If you want to launch exact app, then set below Uri,

```
Uri.parse("SCHEME_NAME://HOST_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME");
```

Comment: Here website need to launch app from mobile browser , not app.(I think, i.e., App deep linking)